# Salesforce custom object in a controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom

How do I add custom objects in controller which I'll just use it within my custom controller for some calculations? I have code below and I get an error:

```
public with sharing class MyCustomController {

    public void MyCustomObject()
    {
        String myName = '';
        Integer myNumber = 0;
    }

    public List<MyCustomObject> custObj = new List<MyCustomObject>();

    public MyCustomController () {}
}
```

Error: Compile Error: Entity is not org-accessible

Comment: are you omitting __c from custom object name intentionally?

Comment: no, I even tried public List<MyCustomObject> custObj__c = new List<MyCustomObject>(); and I received --> Error: Compile Error: Invalid identifier: custObj__c

Comment: List<MyCustomObject__c> custObj = new List<MyCustomObject__c>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work in following way.

```
public with sharing class MyCustomController {

    public List<MyCustomObject__c> custObj{get;set;}
    public void MyCustomObject()
    {
    String myName = '';
    Integer myNumber = 0;
    }

    public MyCustomController () {
         custObj = new List<MyCustomObject__c>();
    }
}
```

Please notice all the changes in the code.

1. I have defined that as property of that class so that it is accessible from the page.
2. Initialization in constructor.

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: MyCustomObject__c

Comment: Do you have any object called MyCustomObject__c ? if not, please create a new object with MyCustomObject or if you want to use any other object replace that with your own custom object API name

Comment: Do I have to create this custom object in my Salesforce Org? Sorry, this could be a dumb question but I'm new to Salesforce

Comment: if you want to use that obviously you need to create that otherwise you can't use that. you can verify this code my replacing MyCustomObject__c with any standard object named Account, Contact, Opportunity  :)